# Errno 13 Permission denied: | Creating a web blocker using ShellExecute

Tags: python, shellexecute

I try to make a simple web blocker but, I have problems with permissions denied... can someone help me?

Here is the code:

```
import win32api, sys

while True:
    try:
        win32api.ShellExecute(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
        url = input("Input URL: ")
        a = open(r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts", "w+")
        a.write("   127.0.0.1       " + url)
        a.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

the message error is:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts'

Comment: When opening the command line, open it as administrator

Comment: Open your cmd window as administrator. C:\Windows is a protected folder, which cannot be accessed by normal user / app